# Replace characters along with newline using regex in vim

Tags: regex, vim, replace

I have the following string

```
Local intf     Local circuit              Dest address    VC ID      Status
-------------  -------------------------- --------------- ---------- ----------
Gi36/1         Eth VLAN 3018              181.181.181.181 3018       UP
10.65.220.180#
--- 19:58:22 ---
482: linuxserver: 2014-07-07T19:58:22: %framework-5-NOTICE: %[pname=TRP-__taskid1]: id: testcase_info_id37
483: linuxserver: 2014-07-07T19:58:22: %framework-5-NOTICE: %[pname=TRP-__taskid1]: starttime: 2014-07-07 19:58:22
484: linuxserver: 2014-07-07T19:58:22: %framework-5-NOTICE: %[pname=TRP-__taskid1]: name: testcase_info_id37
485: linuxserver: 2014-07-07T19:58:22: %framework-5-NOTICE: %[pname=TRP-__taskid1]: Starting execution of subtest testcase_info_id37
+++ 19:58:22 +++
Local intf     Local circuit              Dest address    VC ID      Status
-------------  -------------------------- --------------- ---------- ----------
Gi36/1         Eth VLAN 3018              181.181.181.181 3018       UP
```

I want to replace all the line which contains characters like "linuxserver" in it.

I have tried in vi like below.

```
:%s/.*linuxserver.*//g
```

But, after replacement, I am getting output as

```
    Local intf     Local circuit              Dest address    VC ID      Status
    -------------  -------------------------- --------------- ---------- ----------
    Gi36/1         Eth VLAN 3018              181.181.181.181 3018       UP
    10.65.220.180#
    --- 19:58:22 ---
    //A new line here
    //A new line here
    //A new line here    
    //A new line here    
    +++ 19:58:22 +++
    Local intf     Local circuit              Dest address    VC ID      Status
    -------------  -------------------------- --------------- ---------- ----------
    Gi36/1         Eth VLAN 3018              181.181.181.181 3018       UP
```

I want it to be like as follows,

```
Local intf     Local circuit              Dest address    VC ID      Status
    -------------  -------------------------- --------------- ---------- ----------
    Gi36/1         Eth VLAN 3018              181.181.181.181 3018       UP
    10.65.220.180#
    --- 19:58:22 ---
    +++ 19:58:22 +++
    Local intf     Local circuit              Dest address    VC ID      Status
    -------------  -------------------------- --------------- ---------- ----------
    Gi36/1         Eth VLAN 3018              181.181.181.181 3018       UP
```

How i can achieve this ? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try:

```
:g/linuxserver/d
```

See

```
:help global
```

for more information.

Answer (score 4):

The `:global` command is most appropriate for your problem (`:g/linuxserver/d`), but here is the reason why vim gave you empty lines instead of deleting them. The `.` does not match new lines (see [:help :regex](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/pattern.html#pattern-atoms)):

```
.   (with 'nomagic': \.)                */.* */\.*
    Matches any single character, but not an end-of-line.

\n  matches an end-of-line              */\n*
    When matching in a string instead of buffer text a literal newline
    character is matched.
```

So in order to *delete* the lines, change your regex as follows:

```
:%s/.*linuxserver.*\n//
```

Oh, and the `/g` modifier doesn't make sense in your case because you already match the whole line (`.*` ... `.*`).